# Cors proxy PHP script for hls streams?

Tags: php, node.js, proxy, cors, http-live-streaming

From https://www.npmjs.org/package/corsproxy I downloaded "corsproxy" and successfully installed it on my local notebook as a reverse proxy to add cors headers to my HLS streams (Http Live Streaming).

I can successfully use it like this:

```
http://localhost:9292/my-HLS-url.m3u8
```

My shared Internet web server does not support npm or other js installations and I don't have root access to the server. The server supports PHP only.

Is there a PHP script with same functionality as corsproxy? I would like to use it like this:

```
http://www.myserver.org/corsproxy.php?url=my-HLS-url.m3u8
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever figure out a PHP solution for this?

Comment: Unfortunately not.